# Raycasting with rotated vectors

Tags: game-engine, vector

am trying to setup a simple obstacle avoidance, using a ray sensor facing forward direction of an object.
If this forward sensor hits something i want to send two raycast to the left and right of the hit position.

Am probably having 2 problems, understanding what it means to use vectors instead of objects position with Raycast.
And rotating a vector.

Here's my code

```
def Raycastor(cont):
    obj = cont.owner
    sRay = cont.sensors['sRay']
    if sRay.positive:
        # Debug render ray sensor (Y)
        render.drawLine( obj.worldPosition, sRay.hitPosition, [0,255,0])
        
        # can get the vector between object and hit position
        vectTo = obj.getVectTo(sRay.hitPosition)
        # getting the vector from the list
        vectTo = vectTo[1]
        
        hit_obj, hit_pos, _ = obj.rayCast( vectTo[1], obj)
```

Now i don't know how to rotate that vector, tried

```
matrix = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.pi / 2, 4, "Z")
vectTo[1].rotate(matrix)
```

and many other things but i usually end with a matrix, quaternion or tuples that i don't know  how to use them with raycast or render.drawline for debugging.

So, for raycasting with vectors, does those vectors needs to be vectors pointing from objects to the origin ?

And is there a smart way of rotating a vector by some degrees (or whatever) ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can take the player worldOrientation matrix and rotate it, and then base a vector on this.

```py
rot = obj.worldTransform.copy() @ mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.pi / 2, 4, "Z")
#this assumes that X+ is forward
end = rot @ Vector([10,0,0])
```